# vsDiffMerge.exe /m merge option is working like /t option?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, merge, diff

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 5

I was using successfully vsDiffMerge.exe as the diff and merge tool both in Sourcetree as well as from command line (using the /t and the /m options)

All of a sudden (only thing I can note is Windows update "KB4015217") the vsDiffMerge stopped working in case of merge (the /m option) and instead it started behaving as if it is an automated merge followed by a diff !!

The command line syntax

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe" "$fremote" "$flocal" "$fbase" "$fmerge" /m /t
```

would generate a strange window such as this
[Output of the vsDiffMerge.exe with the /m /t option, same if we use only /m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jHMO.png)

We have tried all the tricks in the book: devenv /resetuserdata , reset all settings from import/export, reset Window layout, and doing a complete VS Repair

Any suggestion how to go about solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

We ended moving to P4Merge to get a working tool for this.

I will close this thread.